# Random post widget script not working on blogger

Tags: javascript

I'm trying do make a random post widget to work on my blog (blogger), but the browser keeps giving me an error saying that the script is unresponsive:
"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://testeshoon.blogspot.pt/:4792"

The script came with the template.
Have tried other scripts from the web but they all do the same.
I'm trying to solve this for the past 2 days, but can't figure out what the problem is.

Can anyone help me? 
Really need this to work, at least, in 2 widgets.

Tried scripts for recent posts and those work just fine, but the ones for random doesn't.

```js
<ul id='random-posts'>
 <script type='text/javaScript'>
  var rdp_numposts = 2;
  var rdp_snippet_length = 100;
  var rdp_info = 'yes';
  var rdp_comment = 'Comments';
  var rdp_disable = 'Comments Disabled';
  var rdp_current = [];
  var rdp_total_posts = 0;
  var rdp_current = new Array(rdp_numposts);

  function totalposts(json) {
   rdp_total_posts = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t
  }
  document.write('<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/feeds/posts/default/-/noticias?alt=json-in-script&max-results=0&callback=totalposts\"><\/script>');

  function getvalue() {
   for (var i = 0; i < rdp_numposts; i++) {
    var found = false;
    var rndValue = get_random();
    for (var j = 0; j < rdp_current.length; j++) {
     if (rdp_current[j] == rndValue) {
      found = true;
      break
     }
    };
    if (found) {
     i--
    } else {
     rdp_current[i] = rndValue
    }
   }
  };

  function get_random() {
   var ranNum = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * (rdp_total_posts - 1));
   return ranNum
  };
 </script>
 <script type='text/javaScript'>
  var _0x3eb4=["\x65\x6E\x74\x72\x79","\x66\x65\x65\x64","\x24\x74","\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65","\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74","\x73\x75\x6D\x6D\x61\x72\x79","","\x72\x65\x70\x6C\x61\x63\x65","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x20","\x6C\x61\x73\x74\x49\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x4F\x66","\x26\x23\x31\x33\x33\x3B","\x6C\x69\x6E\x6B","\x74\x68\x72\x24\x74\x6F\x74\x61\x6C","\x72\x65\x6C","\x61\x6C\x74\x65\x72\x6E\x61\x74\x65","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x70\x75\x62\x6C\x69\x73\x68\x65\x64","\x6D\x65\x64\x69\x61\x24\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x6E\x61\x69\x6C","\x75\x72\x6C","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x33\x2E\x62\x70\x2E\x62\x6C\x6F\x67\x73\x70\x6F\x74\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x2D\x35\x53\x6F\x56\x65\x31\x4B\x36\x4A\x53\x6B\x2F\x55\x74\x6C\x30\x4F\x4F\x6D\x75\x63\x41\x49\x2F\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x41\x46\x36\x45\x2F\x68\x51\x67\x68\x67\x44\x5F\x45\x4A\x64\x51\x2F\x73\x31\x36\x30\x30\x2F\x6E\x6F\x5F\x74\x68\x75\x6D\x62\x2E\x70\x6E\x67","\x3C\x6C\x69\x3E","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65","\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22","\x22\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x22\x6E\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x22\x3E\x3C\x69\x6D\x67\x20\x61\x6C\x74\x3D\x22","\x22\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22","\x22\x2F\x3E\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E","\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x3C\x61\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3D\x22","\x22\x20\x72\x65\x6C\x3D\x22\x6E\x6F\x66\x6F\x6C\x6C\x6F\x77\x22\x20\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x3D\x22","\x22\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x61\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E","\x79\x65\x73","\x3C\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x72\x70\x2D\x69\x6E\x66\x6F\x22\x3E","\x2F","\x20\x2D\x20","\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x70\x61\x6E\x3E","\x3C\x62\x72\x2F\x3E\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x3D\x22\x72\x70\x2D\x73\x6E\x69\x70\x70\x65\x74\x22\x3E","\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x22\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x3A\x62\x6F\x74\x68\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E\x3C\x2F\x6C\x69\x3E","\x3C\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x22\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x22\x2F\x66\x65\x65\x64\x73\x2F\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73\x2F\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x3F\x61\x6C\x74\x3D\x6A\x73\x6F\x6E\x2D\x69\x6E\x2D\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x26\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3D","\x26\x6D\x61\x78\x2D\x72\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74\x73\x3D\x31\x26\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x63\x6B\x3D\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D\x5F\x70\x6F\x73\x74\x73\x22\x3E\x3C\x2F\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3E"];function random_posts(_0x2f3cx2){for(var i=0;i<rdp_numposts;i++){var _0x2f3cx4=_0x2f3cx2[_0x3eb4[1]][_0x3eb4[0]][i];var _0x2f3cx5=_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[3]][_0x3eb4[2]];if(_0x3eb4[4] in _0x2f3cx4){var _0x2f3cx6=_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[4]][_0x3eb4[2]];} else {if(_0x3eb4[5] in _0x2f3cx4){var _0x2f3cx6=_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[5]][_0x3eb4[2]];} else {var _0x2f3cx6=_0x3eb4[6];} ;} ;_0x2f3cx6=_0x2f3cx6[_0x3eb4[7]](/<[^>]*>/g,_0x3eb4[6]);if(_0x2f3cx6[_0x3eb4[8]]<rdp_snippet_length){var _0x2f3cx7=_0x2f3cx6;} else {_0x2f3cx6=_0x2f3cx6[_0x3eb4[9]](0,rdp_snippet_length);var _0x2f3cx8=_0x2f3cx6[_0x3eb4[11]](_0x3eb4[10]);_0x2f3cx7=_0x2f3cx6[_0x3eb4[9]](0,_0x2f3cx8)+_0x3eb4[12];} ;for(var _0x2f3cx9=0;_0x2f3cx9<_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[13]][_0x3eb4[8]];_0x2f3cx9++){if(_0x3eb4[14] in _0x2f3cx4){var _0x2f3cxa=_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[14]][_0x3eb4[2]]+_0x3eb4[10]+rdp_comment;} else {_0x2f3cxa=rdp_disable;} ;if(_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[13]][_0x2f3cx9][_0x3eb4[15]]==_0x3eb4[16]){var _0x2f3cxb=_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[13]][_0x2f3cx9][_0x3eb4[17]];var _0x2f3cxc=_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[18]][_0x3eb4[2]];if(_0x3eb4[19] in _0x2f3cx4){var _0x2f3cxd=_0x2f3cx4[_0x3eb4[19]][_0x3eb4[20]];} else {_0x2f3cxd=_0x3eb4[21];} ;} ;} ;document[_0x3eb4[23]](_0x3eb4[22]);document[_0x3eb4[23]](_0x3eb4[24]+_0x2f3cxb+_0x3eb4[25]+_0x2f3cx5+_0x3eb4[26]+_0x2f3cxd+_0x3eb4[27]);document[_0x3eb4[23]](_0x3eb4[28]+_0x2f3cxb+_0x3eb4[29]+_0x2f3cx7+_0x3eb4[30]+_0x2f3cx5+_0x3eb4[31]);if(rdp_info==_0x3eb4[32]){document[_0x3eb4[23]](_0x3eb4[33]+_0x2f3cxc[_0x3eb4[9]](8,10)+_0x3eb4[34]+_0x2f3cxc[_0x3eb4[9]](5,7)+_0x3eb4[34]+_0x2f3cxc[_0x3eb4[9]](0,4)+_0x3eb4[35]+_0x2f3cxa)+_0x3eb4[36];} ;document[_0x3eb4[23]](_0x3eb4[37]+_0x2f3cx7+_0x3eb4[38]);} ;} ;getvalue();for(var i=0;i<rdp_numposts;i++){document[_0x3eb4[23]](_0x3eb4[39]+rdp_current[i]+_0x3eb4[40]);} ;
 </script>
</ul>
```

Comment: Add console.log(i) in the first line of your for loop an report what happens. You can see its output in the console window of your browser.

Comment: If `rdp_total_posts` is set to zero, and you use that in get_random function  `var ranNum = 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * (rdp_total_posts - 1))` wouldn't the outcome be zero or something less then zero ?

Comment: @Dennis1679, no, it is a callback of the unshared third-party script.

Comment: Your _0x3eb4 variable looks like something intentionally designed to obfuscate the code, which makes me think that the creator of the tool does not want you to use his tool. (without payment). Your code is VERY ugly.

Comment: @Glubus 
Thanks worked just fine!
But have another question now... How do i make it to show only a selected laber/category?

Comment: Cant help you with that unless you have tried stuff yourself, look into jQuery and javascript for stuff like that. Particularly you'll find the jquery functions $.hide() and $.show() useful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you want `k` distinct numbers (random post indexes) from `n` possible numbers. Here is an implementation

```
function getRandomSubset(n, k) {
    if (k > n) {
        //impossible
        return;
    }
    //initializing the result set as empty
    var output = [];
    //creating a variable
    var input;
    //we need k distinct random numbers
    while (k-- > 0) {
        //we get a random integer, 0 <= input < n
        input = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
        //if it is duplicated, increment it inside the n'th modulo class until a new value is found
        while (output.indexOf(input) >= 0) {
            input = (input + 1) % n;
        }
        //store the new distinct value into the results
        output[output.length] = input;
    }
    return output;
}
```

There are many other possible ways.